# Is there a nice way to integrate this?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

I'm trying to integrate:
$$\iiint\limits_{x^2+y^2+z^2\leqslant 1}x^{2n}+y^{2n}+z^{2n}\mathrm{d}V$$
but, I can't seem to find any nice way to do this?

Comment: Did you try converting to spherical coordinate system? Would be the first thing I would try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First note that for symmetry reasons, your integral is equal to
$$
3\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1}z^{2n}dxdydz.
$$
Now use spherical coordinates, which describe the domain of integration very well:
$$
=3\int_{0\leq r\leq 1}\int_{0\leq \phi\leq \pi}\int_{0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi}(r\cos\phi)^{2n}r^2\sin\phi drd\phi\theta.
$$
$$
=3\left(\int_{0}^1r^{2n+2}dr\right)\left(\int_{0}^\pi(\cos\phi)^{2n}\sin\phi d\phi \right)\left( \int_{0}^{2\pi}1d\theta\right)
$$
$$
=3\frac{1}{2n+3}\frac{2}{2n+1}2\pi=\frac{12\pi}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}.
$$

Comment: Could you explain how you arrived at step one?

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
  & \int_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} x^{2n}+y^{2n}+z^{2n} dxdydz\\ 
= & 3 \int_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1}x^{2n} dx dy dz\\
= & 3 \int_{-1}^{1} dx\left( x^{2n} \int_{y^2 + z^2 \le 1 - x^2} dy dz \right)\\
= & 3\pi \int_{-1}^{1} dx \left( x^{2n} (1 - x^2)\right)\\
= & 3 \pi \left( \frac{2}{2n+1} - \frac{2}{2n+3} \right)\\
= & \frac{12 \pi}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}
\end{align}$$